# How to provide multiple fill values using the same aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to pass separate values to change the colors used for fill aesthetics in different geoms.

For example:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(fill = Species), color = 'black', geom = 'bar', fun.y = mean) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Species), color = 'black', shape = 21) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('royal blue', 'red2', 'limegreen'))
```

In this plot, I would like to be able to use separate colors to fill the bars and points. Is this possible? I'm aware of using `scale_fill_manual()` 
to set the colors to whatever values I want, but this will change the fills of both the bars and the points to the same colors.

Here is a semi-working example of what I am trying to do, however, the legend is off...

```
iris_j <- iris %>%
  mutate(Species_bar = factor(paste0(Species, '_bar')))

color.groups <- c('royal blue', 'red2', 'limegreen', NA, 'royal blue', 'white')
names(color.groups) <- c(levels(iris_j$Species), levels(iris_j$Species_bar))

ggplot(iris_j, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(fill = Species_bar), color = 'black', geom = 'bar', fun.y = mean) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Species), color = 'black', shape = 21) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = color.groups)
```

[image]

Comment: There needs to be a rule for setting the colors. I don't see one defined in your question. Use [edit]. DON'T reply in comments.

Comment: Is it necessary for the points to have a black border on them? Because the default would be to use a nonfilled circle for points and map to color, not fill.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely an option but I was hoping to be able to use filled or unfilled shapes. I've updated the question with a hack I came up with. It is not quite working though since the legend is wrong...not sure why the legend shows the bar and point to be the same color...

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, for me the colors are fine

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I just updated the question with an image of what I see when I run that code. Do you get a different result?

Comment: no, but this legend is right, what did you expect ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I guess I would have expected to see two legends, one for the shapes with colors/fill and one for the bars with colors/fill

Comment: you could add this: `guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))`, and add `,show.legend = F` to your geom_point call.

Comment: Check this out and perhaps it can help: http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/#working-with-the-legend

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the limitations of ggplot—an aesthetic can only be mapped to a single variable. Generally speaking, I find it a reasonable limitation, as it forestalls a lot of confusing and hard-to-read graphs. That said, with some creativity, it can be worked around, e.g. by coloring the points with the `color` aesthetic, and then overplotting to add a stroke:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
    stat_summary(aes(fill = Species), color = 'black', geom = 'bar', fun.y = mean) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +    # add colored points
    geom_point(color = 'black', shape = 21, show.legend = TRUE) +    # add point strokes (including in legend)
    scale_color_manual(values = c('royal blue', 'red2', 'limegreen')) +    # define point colors
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, 'royal blue', 'white'))    # define bar colors
```

[image]

To separate the legends, specify a different name for each. To add a stroke to the points in the legend, you'll need to effectively rebuild it in `guide_legend`. (According to the docs, supplying a named vector to `show.legend` should work, but in practice it fails.)

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
    stat_summary(aes(fill = Species), color = 'black', geom = 'bar', fun.y = mean) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Species)) + 
    geom_point(color = 'black', shape = 21) +
    scale_color_manual('points', values = c('royal blue', 'red2', 'limegreen'), 
                       guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, color = 'black', 
                                                                fill = c('royal blue', 'red2', 'limegreen')))) + 
    scale_fill_manual('bars', values = c(NA, 'royal blue', 'white'))
```

[image]

Such an approach will not generalize to a plot where color is already being used otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice solution. I think the `alpha = 0` workaround is bit more flexible, though. Any idea why in my hack around solution I end up with duplicated legend items that don't quite match the real plot (i.e., all legend objects are showing the bar and point even though each are filled differently)?

Comment: Generally, yes, alpha is useful, though it doesn't fix this problem, which still requires both color and fill. As for your legend, you passed it a vector with 6 levels, so the legend will have 6 elements. Since it's built assuming the geoms are the same across levels, it adds both bars and points to both. tl;dr: It's a side effect of making it do something it doesn't want you to do.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few little things to try that you could build off of.

First up, if you don't need to use a filled shape, you can just map color to the species in `geom_point`, so you have a color scale and a fill scale. In this case, I changed the label for fill to mark it as being the means, to show how you can split these into two legends.

```r
library(tidyverse)
light_colors <- c("#87CEEB", "#FFB6C1", "#FF8C69")
dark_colors <- c("#22A0D6", "#E33650", "#BF411B")

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(aes(fill = Species), geom = "bar", fun.y = mean) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = light_colors) +
  scale_color_manual(values = dark_colors) +
  labs(fill = "Mean by Species")
```

[image]

Second, if you *do* need a filled shape, let `geom_point` get a fill scale and hack the bars to have a color instead. One way to do that is by making what look like bars but are actually really big `geom_segment`s. I changed the size in the legend to make the legend keys not ridiculously huge.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(aes(xend = Species, yend = 0, color = Species), geom = "segment", fun.y = mean, size = 30, lineend = "butt") +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Species), color = "black", shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = light_colors) +
  scale_color_manual(values = dark_colors, guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4)))
```

[image]

Third way, make a data frame of averages and give it a variable to denote that it's got averages, then add a variable to the original data frame to denote that it's observations. Then you can map the interaction of type with species to get separate colors in one fill scale.

```r
avgs <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  mutate(type = "Mean")

iris %>%
  select(Species, Sepal.Length) %>%
  mutate(type = "Observation") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = interaction(Species, type))) +
  geom_col(data = avgs) +
  geom_point(color = "black", shape = 21)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not quite a perfect solution, but it may be a sufficient workaround

```
     cols_1 <- c("red", "green", "blue")
     cols_2 <- c("orange", "purple", "yellow")
     ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +  
       geom_point(aes(color = Species)) + # Using color instead of fill 
       stat_summary(aes(fill = Species), color = 'black', geom = 'bar', fun.y = mean, alpha = c(0.5, 0.05, 1)) +  
     scale_color_manual(values = cols_1) + # colors your points 
     scale_fill_manual(values = cols_2) # fills your Summary Bars
```

Adjust the colors, alpha, and other graphical parameters as you see fit.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I'm looking for...I'd specifically like to provide separate colors to fill so that I could, for instance, have one of the three bars filled in and the others empty but have all the points filled in with colors

Comment: I see. It's fairly problematic you're trying to provide two different interpretations of `fill` to the same factor. I considered editing your data to create more factors/levels, but since you're coloring by the same value you use to define your x axis, even that will fail. Do you want to color by the same factor you use to set your x axis?

Comment: you could feed alpha to the aes to do that, set it to 0 for the transparent bars

Comment: That is a good idea regarding the alpha, however, how would you make it possible to make either the shapes or the bars transparent? I am asking because this is being built into a shiny app and I want to be able to change either.

Comment: I updated the `stat_summary()` command to show varying alpha levels. My advice for implementing Shiny would be to set your alpha to be `reactive()` and have it be based upon `c(input$1, input$2, input$3)` . This doesn't really account for setting the transparency for the points themselves. Hopefully that's not a deal-breaker.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution. I didn't realize that you can list alpha values outside the `aes()` since listing colors/fill is not accepted

Comment: You're right about listing colors/fill. I just tried to do something similar in a ShinyApp myself by using 'fill' for all the points, but that didn't quite work since all the point shapes came out distorted (21-25). You might be able to do what you originally wanted, 2 aesthetics to the same input, if you create a new stat with its own mapping: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html ... I just have no clue how though.But just making sure, everything works for you on your end now?